# Why flutter read my List<String> as List<List<dynamic>>?

Tags: flutter

So I have List inside an object, I need to create Row widget for every element of the list.
here is my object structure:

```
class Paket {
 String name;
 String durasi;
 String berat;
 String harga;
 List<String> extras;

 Paket(
  {
    required this.nama,
    required this.durasi,
    required this.berat,
    required this.harga,
    required this.extras,
  });

 static List<Paket> fetchAll(){
  return[
   Paket(
      nama: "Paket Kiloan",
      durasi: "3",
      berat: "1",
      harga: "15.000",
      extras: ['Gratis pengantaran', 'Diskon menjadi Rp 12.000']
   ),
  ];
 }
}
```

Then I get the data like this `List<Paket> paket = Paket.fetchAll();`
This is how I show the data

```
ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: paket.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      return Container(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(paket[index].nama),
                                SizedBox(height: size.height*.01),
                                Text('• Harga paket : Rp '+paket[index].harga+'\n• Lama cuci : '+paket[index].durasi+' Hari\n• Minimal berat : '+paket[index].berat+' Kg'),
                                paket[index].extras.length!=0?Divider(color: Color(0xffE5E6E6)):Container(),
                                for(var i=0;i< paket[index].extras.length;i++) Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Color(0xff0EB37E), size: 10),
                                    SizedBox(width: size.width*.005),
                                    Text(paket[index].extras[i])
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                )
```

I get this error "type '`List<List<dynamic>>`' is not a subtype of type '`List<String>`' of 'function result'" why I get that error?

Comment: this code has many missing closing parenthesis is it working fine your side?

Comment: haha, sorry I tried to simplified the code, end up deleting some of those

Comment: already edit the question, thanks

Comment: check answer below

Answer (score 0):

There are some missing parenthesis in your code and also error in Paket Class Variable declaration.

First fix nama in Paket Class it's declared as name:

```
class Paket {
  String nama;
```

then replace your screen code with code below:

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: paket.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(paket[index].nama),
                      SizedBox(height: size.height * .01),
                      Text('• Harga paket : Rp ' +
                          paket[index].harga +
                          '\n• Lama cuci : ' +
                          paket[index].durasi +
                          ' Hari\n• Minimal berat : ' +
                          paket[index].berat +
                          ' Kg'),
                      paket[index].extras.isNotEmpty
                          ? const Divider(color: Color(0xffE5E6E6))
                          : Container(),
                      for (var i = 0; i < paket[index].extras.length; i++)
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            const Icon(Icons.check_circle,
                                color: Color(0xff0EB37E), size: 10),
                            SizedBox(width: size.width * .005),
                            Text(paket[index].extras[i])
                          ],
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          })
```

[image]

Comment: the only thing change in the show code is `paket[index].extras.isNotEmpty? const Divider(color: Color(0xffE5E6E6)) : Container()` right?

Comment: can you explain a bit more about the error in Paket Class Variable declaration

Comment: actually you have declared in Paket class "String? name" and in it's constructor and other places your using "name" you can check in your question.